# Kivy - save full scrollview to image format

Tags: python, kivy

Does anyone know how make this (saving a scrollview stitched together as a series of images about the height of the screen) a reality?

There is the save_to_png method for every widget, but this only saves the currently visible portion of the screen.  I'm not sure how to scroll down automatically by the height of the screen, and of course it would be better if there was a simple method for saving all of a widget to image, even if not currently rendered on the screen.

Any pointers on how to go about this?

Comment: Um... the save_to_png method?  You can call it on any kivy widget and it will save all currently visible children of the widget and the widget to a png file of your choice.  All you have to do is define an on_press method and then invoke the export_to_png function of the widget.  For example, if the widget was defined in a python class, then you only have to do this from one of the class' methods:

        `self.export_to_png (fileName)`

Comment: Use self.scroll_to()